# Domino Xpages based Web page not recognizing groups

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

My web app consists of 2 databases (one programming and one data). People who are listed explicitly in the ACL can access the db after logging in. People in a group cannot.

Have never seen this before. What could possibly be causing this.

Comment: Is the group marked as a group in the top right of the ACL?  Is the group name in the address book?

Comment: And is the group type "Access Control" or "Multi-Purpose"?

Comment: Rob go it right. Can't believe I made this mistake. The group was not listed as a group, but as a person. Rob, if you answer the question I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that the group is marked as a group in the top right of the ACL.  If it is, also check that the group name is in the address book.